# backbone.js: trouble persisting simple Model to localStorage

Tags: backbone.js

I'm getting started with backbone, I used [this localStorage adapter](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/blob/master/backbone.localStorage.js). 
Here's my test code:

```
cartStatus = Backbone.Model.extend({
    localStorage: new Store("cartStatus"),
    currentClientId: ""
});

var myStatus = new cartStatus;

$(function () {
    myStatus.fetch();
    alert("loaded" + myStatus.get("currentClientId"));
    myStatus.set({ "currentClientId": "abc" });
    myStatus.save();
});
```

If I load the page multiple times it says `loaded: undefined` every time.
however, after my second load I would expect `loaded: abc` every time.
when I inspect my localstorage after 2 loads I see this:

```
cartStatus-d2a7b64d-2f15-a741-9a8c-e254b4a13682 {"0":{"currentClientId":"abc","id":"dd5e0e47-9356-ea30-2de3-75a041848b88"},"currentClientId":"abc","id":"d2a7b64d-2f15-a741-9a8c-e254b4a13682"}
cartStatus dd5e0e47-9356-ea30-2de3-75a041848b88,d2a7b64d-2f15-a741-9a8c-e254b4a13682
cartStatus-dd5e0e47-9356-ea30-2de3-75a041848b88 {"currentClientId":"abc","id":"dd5e0e47-9356-ea30-2de3-75a041848b88"}
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

**Edit**
I've created a jsfiddle demonstrating this (run it twice) http://jsfiddle.net/Myster/fE9eQ/3/

Comment: Even though it's localstorage, have you tried doing the alert in the `success` options for `fetch`?

Comment: The success callback is triggered (see js fiddle in edit above)

Answer (score 0):

@tkone, you are suggesting the correct answer I think. The fetch is async, so unless you use jquery deferreds or do the model set/save in the success callback, then this will be the behavior.

```
cartStatus = Backbone.Model.extend({
    localStorage: new Store("cartStatus"),
    currentClientId: ""
});

var myStatus = new cartStatus();

$(function () {
    debugger;
    myStatus.fetch({
        success: function(x) {
            document.write('myStatus.fetch - success !<br />');
            myStatus.set("currentClientId", "abc" );
            myStatus.save();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In this example, if I refresh the page 4 times I end up with 4 items in my localStorage (each subsequent verison has the previous version nested inside), where I want just the one item to be updated.